# How do I use decimals when spacing a graphic

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to space some lines on a graphic I am creating however I cant seem yo be able to input a decimal number (3.5) as the value for the space between the lines in the graphics.  at the moment I have input the value 4 into the code however this is wrong.

the code I am using is below;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    g.drawLine(185, 130 - 4*i, 260, 130 - 4*i);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I would input the decimals as the value?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Graphics2D` Object instead. Your code could look like this:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    g.draw(new Line2D.Double(185, 130 - 3.5*i, 260, 130 - 3.5*i);
```